# How to add a repeated element to an array in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat, getelementsbyclassname

I'm working on a schoolproject. I created some lines with ng-repeat. Now when I want to add them with 'addElementsByClassName' the arraylength will still be 0.

This is in my html:

```
<tr class = "ingredient" ng-repeat = "i in data.Ingredients">
    <td>{{ i.Ingredient.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ i.Ingredient.Amount_g }}</td>
</tr>
```

This is in my controller:

```
    $scope.allIngredients = [];
    $scope.dashboard = MainService.getDashboard ();

    $scope.dashboard.then (function (data) { //receive the data from a server via MainService
        $scope.data = data;
        $scope.allIngredientRows = document.getElementsByClassName ('ingredient');
        console.log ($scope.allIngredients.length);
    });
```

I want my rows inside that array so I can do something with them later. But now the length of the array remains 0.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName ('ingredient') will give you an array of all the elements who has the class ingredient. you need to check the response data in your service function call back

Comment: Yea but I want to modify the rows, not the data.

Comment: What does your data object - or whatever - look like?

Comment: Its an Object with 3 arrays, one with Ingredients, one with nutrions and one with drinks. Everything has a name, an amount, ...

Comment: You are approaching this wrong...you don't look in the DOM....you already have the data in your array. A controller should never have any dom methods in it

Comment: Oh, how should I approach it then? I want to add more elements inside the rows later.

Answer (score 1):

**#1** Your approach is wrong.
You should operate on data, not on the html elements.
Try this way:

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in ingredients">
    <td>{{ item.Ingredient.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.Ingredient.Amount_g }}</td>
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.ingredients = [];

MainService.getDashboard().then (function (data) {
    $scope.ingredients = data.Ingredients;

    console.log ($scope.ingredients.length); // Amount of your ingredients
});
```

When you want to add more items, use:

```
$scope.ingredients.push(newIngredient);
```

or

```
$scope.ingredients = $scope.ingredients.concat(newIngredients);
```

**#2** Advice

But I recommend you read about angular.js good practices, naming conventions in javascript, and think about your json structure.

For example:

1. Instead of $scope use: [controllerAs View Syntax](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y030)
2. Follow the rules: [JavaScript Style Guide and Coding Conventions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving the Angular digest cycle any time to run.

> I want my rows inside that array so I can do something with them later.

Try retrieving the row count right before that 'later' use. It should be updated.
If not, try using $scope.$$apply() to induce a digest cycle.